# Creating new dictionary from values in a previous dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function I have to write (with how I attempted to write it). Obviously there's something wrong with my code, or I wouldn't be posting here :) I know what is wrong based on the message it gives me when I try to use it, and I understand what it is - writing image_dict[0][1] doesn't work because the key isn't 0. I need to know how the exact key to use that but of course the key could be anything so I am wondering if I could easily change my code so that it works for any key. For example, could I put something in place of the 0 so that it works for all keys, rather than having to specify the exact key? Thanks!

```
def create_date_dict(image_dict):
'''(dict) -> dict

Given an image dictionary, return a new dictionary
where the key is a date and the value  is a list
of filenames of images taken on that date.

>>> d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday']}
>>> date_d = create_date_dict(d)
>>> date_d == {'2017-11-03': ['image1.jpg']}
True
'''
result = {}
for (k, v) in image_dict.items():
    result[image_dict[0][1]] = [image_dict[0]]
return result
```

Comment: How are handling the multiple images having same date?

Comment: also try this : for key in image_dict:
    result[image_dict[key][1]] = key

Comment: no that doesn't work since key isn't defined as anything

Comment: try this : for key in image_dict.keys(): result[image_dict[key][1]] = key

Comment: for key in image_dict should work in Python3+ as it is shorthand of  for key in image_dict.keys()

Comment: it says  unhashable type: 'list' when i try that do you know why it might be saying that

Comment: can you share your image_dict?

Comment: I'm just using d from the doc string example

Comment: Also confused at why the doc string has the True thing at the end that seems unnecessary

Comment: That means you do not have anything in image_dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first understand the actual problem by an example :

> Example code :

For these types of list problems there is a pattern :

So suppose you have a list :

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]
```

And you want to convert this to a dict as the first element of the tuple as key and second element of the tuple. something like :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [5], 2007: [4]}
```

But there is a catch you also want that those keys which have different values but keys are same like (2006,1) and (2006,5) keys are same but values are different. you want that those values append with only one key so expected output :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [1, 5], 2007: [4]}
```

for this type of problem we do something like this:

first create a new dict then we follow this pattern:

```
if item[0] not in new_dict:
    new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
else:
    new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

So we first check if key is in new dict and if it already then add the value of duplicate key to its value:

full code:

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]

new_dict={}

for item in a:
    if item[0] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    else:
        new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(new_dict)
```

> Now your solution without any external module:

```
d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], 'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-09-04','Happy Monday'], 'image3.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Monday']}
def create_date_dict(image_dict):
    date_dict={}
    for key,value in image_dict.items():
        if value[1] not in date_dict:
            date_dict[value[1]]=[key] #notice here carefully , we have to store key in list so we can append values to it in else part of condition we did `[key]` , not `key` 
        elif key not in date_dict[value[1]]:
            date_dict[value[1]].append(key)

    return date_dict

print(create_date_dict(d))
```

output:

```
{'2017-09-04': ['image2.jpg'], '2017-11-03': ['image3.jpg', 'image1.jpg']}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another very cool method I learnt from [@coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) to get rid of importing  :

```
# Data from @Miraj50
d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], 'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-09-04','Happy Monday'], 'image3.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Monday']}

k = {}

for x, y in d.items():
    k.setdefault(y[1], []).append(x)

{'2017-09-04': ['image2.jpg'], '2017-11-03': ['image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg']}
```

Comment: Thats Nice! Learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

I used a `defaultdict` to get what you wanted. See this example.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], 'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-09-04','Happy Monday'], 'image3.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Monday']}
newd = defaultdict(list)
for i in d:
    newd[d[i][1]].append(i)
print(dict(newd))
```

Or without collections (Added by @antonvbr)

```
d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], 'image2.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-09-04','Happy Monday'], 'image3.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Monday']}

newd = {}

# Loop over the dictionary d
for img, metadata in d.items():

    #Extract the date from 'metadata'
    date = metadata[1]

    # If key doesn't exist create an empty list
    if not newd.get(date):
        newd[date] = []

    # Add item to list inside dict
    newd[date].append(img)

print(newd)
```

Output:

```
{'2017-11-03': ['image1.jpg', 'image3.jpg'], '2017-09-04': ['image2.jpg']}
```

Comment: thanks! do you know if there's an easy way similar to mine to do it without importing default dict? if not thats fine

Comment: @Rir8 I hope you can see why your method doesn't work. It doesn't append anything. The reason I used a *defaultdict*, is that each key will be a list *by deafult* and all I have to do is to append. If you want to do it your way, then you would have to check if a  particular key exists. If it exists, append to it otherwise make a new key-value pair. Right now you are just making one.

Comment: @Rir8 I took the liberty and edited this answer to add what you asked for. But collections is a standard library that is often used for tasks like these.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thanks a lot for improving the answer.

Comment: @Miraj50 I didn't improve it as yours was perfectly fine.

Comment: @Miraj50 what do you think about my answer : )

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'image1.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Friday'], 'image2.jpg': 
['UTSC', '2017-09-04','Happy Monday'], 'image3.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-
03','Happy Monday'], 'image4.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-11-03','Happy Monday'], 
'image5.jpg': ['UTSC', '2017-01-04','Happy Monday']}
new_d={}
print len(d)
list_1=[]

for i1 in d:
    print i1
    list_1.append(i1)
    print list_1
for i in range(0,len(list_1)):
    count=0
    for j in range(1,len(list_1)):
        x=list_1[i]
        y=list_1[j]
        if d[x][1]==d[y][1]:
            if d[x][1] not in new_d:
                new_d[d[x][1]]=[]
                new_d[d[x][1]].append(x)
                count=1
            elif x not in new_d[d[x][1]]:
                new_d[d[x][1]].append(x)
                count=1

    if count != 0:
        if d[x][1] not in new_d:
            new_d[d[x][1]]=[]
            new_d[d[x][1]].append(x)
        elif x not in new_d[d[x][1]]:
            new_d[d[x][1]].append(x)


print new_d
```

Comment: Sorry but just because something works doesn't mean it is good. Python is all about writing easy **readable** and maintainable code. It doesn't have to be super-fast but it has to be efficient and handle errors.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thank you for your comments, will improve my answers accordingly..!! am in the learning phase...